# Detect window closed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, window

I'm creating a chat client which uses a database to check the status of a session 0-waiting, 1-running, 2-closed.

I have a close button which will change the status to 2 but I was wondering, how do I detect if the browser is closed just by pressing x?

The main reason for this is I don't want the session showing up as running when one of the participants has closed their browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `unload` and `onbeforeunload` events:

```
window.onunload = window.onbeforeunload = function (){...};
```

It's better to register to both of the events to be sure the callback will fire.

Comment: @THeK. Added answer for chrome. Try it

Answer (score 5):

You could listen for the [onbeforeunload-event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload) with JavaScript, which is fired when the browser window is closed.

As you tagged the question with jquery, you can use [.unload()](http://api.jquery.com/unload/):

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  // Do some ajax-request to kill the session
});
```

Without jQuery it would be:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   // Do some ajax-request to kill the session
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **beforeunload** event, because **unload** event is deprecated in jQuery version 1.8 and the beforeunload event fires whenever the user leaves your page.

```
$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
    return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
})
```